# How to calculate complexity of merge-sort that divides into 1 third and 2 thids?

Tags: mergesort

I have a merge-sort algorithm that intead of splitting the array by 2 halfs each recursion, it splits the array by 1 third and 2 thirds.
I am trying to prove that the worst case complexity is also nlogn but I don't know how exactly. How can I prove that?